# How to use Cavalieri?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

How can I compute the volume of $$S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3\, |\, x^2+y^2 \le\frac{1}{(1+z)^2}, 0\le z\le 1\}$$
by exclusively using integration?
I know that I can use Cavalieri, but I don't understand the solution, a step by step explanation would be much appreciated. The result we are looking for is $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: So you do not want to view it as a solid of revolution? I suggest that you view this as the volume that appears when rotating $x=1/(1+z)$ around the $z$-axis (and when $0\leq z\leq 1$). Then $$\text{volume}\,(S)=\int_0^1 \pi \frac{1}{(1+z)^2}\,dz=\bigl[-\pi/(1+z)\bigr]_0^1=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$ It cannot be easier, I think.

Comment: Yes thank you, but what is the intuition behind it? How do I know that I have to rotate $x$ around the $z$-axis?

Comment: See here, for instance: http://www.phengkimving.com/calc_of_one_real_var/12_app_of_the_intgrl/12_03_finding_vol_by_slicing.htm

Comment: The appearance of $x^2+y^2$ implies that the domain is rotational symmetric in those variables, i.e. that $S$ is a body obtained via rotation around the $z$-axis.

Comment: Perfect, thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [cylindrical polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) to get the volume as the following integral
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{0}^1\int_{0}^{1\over 1+z}rdrdzd\theta =\pi\int_0^1{1\over(1+z)^2}dz={\pi\over2}
$$

Comment: how to find upper and lower limit of the integrals?

Comment: Your set is $\{(r,\theta,z):r^2\le{1\over(z+1)^2},z\in[0,1]\}$. The first inequality gives the upper bound for $r$ as ${1\over1+z}$